# how can i load/ populated textarea content by Ajax with TinyMCE editor

Tags: php, ajax

i have the following code i'm trying to populate textarea using ajax with tinyMCE editor content when edit button is clicked.... but it does not populate the textarea in tinyMCE, it works fine for other text fields.

My Ajax code is as follows:

```
<script>
        window.actionEvents = {
            'click .edit-question': function (e, value, row, index) {
                $('#question_id').val(row.id);
                tinyMCE.get('#edit_question').setContent(row.question);

                //$('#edit_question').html(row.question);

        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. PS; this probably is a common problem. Google might be able to help you out.

Comment: what type of formatting...?